# Get allocated memory size for CUDA buffer

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to get the size of allocated memory buffer by pointer?

All I found are `cudaPointerGetAttributes` function and `cudaPointerAttributes` structure, but latter has no field `size` or something useful to define the size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. [`cuMemGetAddressRange()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM_1g64fee5711274a2a0573a789c94d8299b) from the [Driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/) allows you to retrieve base address and size for any device pointer from a CUDA allocation.